# Skip the usual behaviour of select Input using javascript

Tags: javascript, events, select, preventdefault

I have a form having select Input with some options in the drop down option list.

Requirement: On click of the select Input I need to check validation of form.If the form is incomplete I need to skip the behaviour of select input i.e do not show the option list.
However if the form is complete the select input should show me the options(i.e normal behaviour).

Problem : I did try event.preventDefault() to skip the further action assuming that the select input will not show me the options if the form was incomplete.
But this aint workin

Find the code:

```
$('selectInput').addEvent('click', function(event){
  if(!validateForm()){
    if(event.preventDefault){
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      //IE
      event.returnValue = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try `return false;` ? This usually works to prevent default behaviour of submot buttons, it might work for select's...

Comment: yups I tried..The problem is Before even executing the code..the option list is shown.So what I am thinking is we should manually close the option list.How to implement is the hurdle i am facing

Comment: this solved→ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141398/cannot-preventdefault-via-firefox-on-a-select/33566917#33566917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable/enable the select everytime the validation parameters are changed ?

Otherwise, I noticed you are using jQuery, so you could imple,ent your own or one that is already made with your features...

Comment: Oh yes , 'disabling-enabling' logic was my back up option.Thought of askin you guys to get better optimal ideas if I may have missed.

Comment: @Zohaib I guess even if you had found an answer to your exact problem, it would be largely dependent on the different browsers. If you really want this feature, either change the style of disabled fields to look like the enabled one or use jquery custom controls

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to add the options in your onclick. If the validation passes, add the option otherwise don't do anything.

Comment: yups I even thought that. But this then makes even think for Clearing those option list again if the  form which was initially valid but then while updating the same form the user(left some fields incomplete)  making  the form invalid again.

Comment: If you don't have many to-be-validated fields, you could just add a validation function to them, to make sure if the form aint valid, the options are removed. Just form the top of my mind, I understand it aint the optimized method.