# Cannot preventDefault via Firefox on a <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Trying to preventDefault a keydown event in Firefox on a `<select>` but it does not work.

Any workaround?

For once something that even IE handles but Firefox does not!

See the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/p8FNv/1/

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    <option value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#select").keydown(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();        
    });         
});
```

Comment: Keydown in `<select>`? Maybe you mean `.focus()` or `.change()`??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Prevent keydown events - such as when the user enters a key and the select chooses a value which starts with that key

Answer (score 4):

This is not much elegant but works:

```
$("select").keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = this;
    elem.disabled=true;
    setTimeout(function() { elem.disabled = false; }, 0);
});
```

A greeting.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me on Firefox 19.  I am assuming your intention is to prevent the select value from changing via keyboard input when a user types in a value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valueToKeep;
    $("#select").keypress(function (event) {
        $(this).val(valueToKeep);
    });
    $("#select").keydown(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        valueToKeep = $(this).val();

    });         
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8FNv/11/)

Comment: No sorry, this is not working. If I select the dropdown and then hit 'W' it selects Wednesday. Expected to stay on Monday and never move from it no matter what key is pressed

Comment: Oh OK.  This only works when the options aren't expanded.  I'll see if I can accomodate this new requirement

Comment: It appears to be a bug that is over 7 years old: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=291082.  You might be able to give the illusion it's working using element cloning and absolute positioning and some all-around JS trickery.

Comment: @danronmoon 12 years now, but who's counting... :)
I'm in Firefox 55.0.2 (32-bit) and still get that (for keydown, keyup and keypress events)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want another option to be selected when you press a key. I believe this is browser specific implementation and doesn't fire an event. What you might have to do is build out your own select imitation using regular elements and jquery. this could get very complicated depending on how crazy you want to get but here's a small start.

HTML:

```
<div class="imitateSelect>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imitateSelect div{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.imitateSelect div').first().show();

$('.imitateSelect div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().slideDown();
});
```

etc. etc.

Another option is to use a plugin like [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Take a look at what they've done. If you remove the input bar, you wil get select functionality and keypresses won't go change the selected option.

Comment: This is what I am hoping to avoid - I already have a lot of code tied into regular selects which would all have to be overhauled if the dropdowns were not regular selects anymore. But Chosen does look very nice indeed!

Comment: I understand you want to avoid it, but I don't think you can

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the selection change on keydown, try to add the entity `&shy;` ([soft hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen)) before the labels.

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<script>
// working fine in PC and mobile
$('#select').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    setTimeout(function(self) {
        self.show();
    }, 0, $(this))
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```